# Close other dropdown on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on two custom dropdown that displays fruits and animals. It closes when you select or click again the field and click outside the element, my problem is when I open both dropdown, Their options doesn't hide.

What I want is to close other dropdowns after I click a new dropdown.

Hope you understand me.

thanks.

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  // e.stopPropagation();
  var container = $(".custom-dropdown");
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.custom-dropdown .options').hide();
  }
});
$('.custom-dropdown .options li').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').addClass('change');
});
$('.custom-dropdown').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.options').toggle();
});

$('.custom-dropdown .options ul li').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

```css
  .col {
   display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .custom-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
  }
  .custom-dropdown input {
    width: 100% ;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(77, 85, 133, 0.3);
    height: 24px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgba(110, 118, 164, 0.4);
  }
  .custom-dropdown .options {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .custom-dropdown .options ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .custom-dropdown .options li {
    color: #4D5585;
    background-color: #DDD;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    height: initial;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    position: initial;
    background-image: none;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="animals" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>cat</li>
          <li>dog</li>
          <li>cow</li>
          <li>chicken</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="fruits" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>banana</li>
          <li>apple</li>
          <li>watermelon</li>
          <li>melon</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this you need to hide all the other `.options` elements that are visible and related to other dropdowns. To do that you can use this line within your `.custom-dropdown` click handler:

```
$('.custom-dropdown').not(this).find('.options').hide();
```

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  // e.stopPropagation();
  var container = $(".custom-dropdown");
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.custom-dropdown .options').hide();
  }
});

$('.custom-dropdown .options li').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').addClass('change');
});

$('.custom-dropdown').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.options').toggle();
  $('.custom-dropdown').not(this).find('.options').hide();
});

$('.custom-dropdown .options ul li').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.custom-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
}

.custom-dropdown input {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(77, 85, 133, 0.3);
  height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(110, 118, 164, 0.4);
}

.custom-dropdown .options {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom-dropdown .options ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.custom-dropdown .options li {
  color: #4D5585;
  background-color: #DDD;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  height: initial;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  position: initial;
  background-image: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="animals" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>cat</li>
          <li>dog</li>
          <li>cow</li>
          <li>chicken</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="fruits" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>banana</li>
          <li>apple</li>
          <li>watermelon</li>
          <li>melon</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="planets" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>mercury</li>
          <li>venus</li>
          <li>earth</li>
          <li>mars</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add `$(".options:visible").hide();`. This will hide any `.options` that is visible aka "open"

```
$('.custom-dropdown').click(function() {
  $(".options:visible").not(this).hide();
  $(this).find('.options').toggle();
});
```

Also, you can merge 2 of your functions into one.

```
$('.custom-dropdown .options li').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').addClass('change');
});

$('.custom-dropdown .options ul li').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

Since this is the same trigger, just merge them together as this:

```
$('.custom-dropdown .options ul li').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').addClass('change');
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  // e.stopPropagation();
  var container = $(".custom-dropdown");
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.custom-dropdown .options').hide();
  }
});
$('.custom-dropdown .options li').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').addClass('change');
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').val($(this).text());
});
$('.custom-dropdown').click(function() {
  $(".options:visible").not(this).hide();
  $(this).find('.options').toggle();
});
```

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.custom-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
}

.custom-dropdown input {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(77, 85, 133, 0.3);
  height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(110, 118, 164, 0.4);
}

.custom-dropdown .options {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom-dropdown .options ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.custom-dropdown .options li {
  color: #4D5585;
  background-color: #DDD;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  height: initial;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  position: initial;
  background-image: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="animals" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>cat</li>
          <li>dog</li>
          <li>cow</li>
          <li>chicken</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="fruits" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>banana</li>
          <li>apple</li>
          <li>watermelon</li>
          <li>melon</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this breaks the `toggle()` logic when repeatedly clicking the same `.options`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Cheers, can't believe i missed that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself a bunch of JavaScript code and use pure CSS instead to handle showing/hiding the dropdown menu.

```js
$('.custom-dropdown .options ul li').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').val($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.custom-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
}

.custom-dropdown input {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(77, 85, 133, 0.3);
  height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(110, 118, 164, 0.4);
}

.custom-dropdown .options {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom-dropdown .options ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.custom-dropdown .options li {
  color: #4D5585;
  background-color: #DDD;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  height: initial;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  position: initial;
  background-image: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.custom-dropdown input:focus + .options, .custom-dropdown .options:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="animals" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>cat</li>
          <li>dog</li>
          <li>cow</li>
          <li>chicken</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="fruits" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>banana</li>
          <li>apple</li>
          <li>watermelon</li>
          <li>melon</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that you need to consider in your code:

1. Add `e.stopPropagation();` in the `$('.custom-dropdown .options ul li').click()` function so that the dropdown is not shown again due to click event from `$('.custom-dropdown').click()`
2. You can hide all the `.option` element first and then show the current clicked `.option` element inside the `$('.custom-dropdown').click()` function.

Using this code, you can close the current dropdown also after you have selected the option from the dropdown which is a natural behaviour of a dropdown.

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  // e.stopPropagation();
  var container = $(".custom-dropdown");
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $('.custom-dropdown .options').hide();
  }
});
$('.custom-dropdown .options li').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').addClass('change');
});
$('.custom-dropdown').click(function() {
  $('.custom-dropdown .options').hide()
  $(this).find('.options').toggle();
});

$('.custom-dropdown .options ul li').click(function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.custom-dropdown').find('input').val($(this).text());
  $(this).closest('.options').hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.custom-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
}

.custom-dropdown input {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(77, 85, 133, 0.3);
  height: 24px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: rgba(110, 118, 164, 0.4);
}

.custom-dropdown .options {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}

.custom-dropdown .options ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.custom-dropdown .options li {
  color: #4D5585;
  background-color: #DDD;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  height: initial;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  position: initial;
  background-image: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="animals" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>cat</li>
          <li>dog</li>
          <li>cow</li>
          <li>chicken</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="custom-dropdown">
      <input type="text" placeholder="fruits" readonly>
      <div class="options">
        <ul>
          <li>banana</li>
          <li>apple</li>
          <li>watermelon</li>
          <li>melon</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why make a each loop? why not just `('.custom-dropdown .options').hide()`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen agree with that :)